# Using class like an object in Python

Tags: python, class, object

I am learning from *Learn Python the hard way* where I have come across a study drill where they want to know that whether a class can be used like an object.

As I have experimented:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "in here"
    def cat(self,name):
        print "my cat ",name
```

Here if I write `A.cat(A(),"Tom")`, it works and found out that its call unbound method. Now, does that mean I can assume that classes can be used like an object?

Comment: If memory serves, Python has a meta class which is the class for a class.  So in that context, class is indeed an object; it is an instance of the metaclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Everything* in Python is an object, including classes.

This means you can reference classes, passing them around like arguments, store them in attributes, (extra) names, lists, dictionaries, etc.

This is perfectly normal in Python:

```
class_map = {
    'foo': A,
    'bar': SomeOtherClass,
    'baz': YetAnother,
}

instance = class_map[some_variable]()
```

Now it depends on `some_variable` what class was picked to create an instance; the `class_map` dictionary values are all classes.

Classes are themselves instances of their *type*; this is called their [*metaclass*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). You can produce a new class by calling `type()` with a name, a sequence of base classes, and a mapping defining the attributes of the class:

```
type('DynamicClass', (), {'foo': 'bar'})
```

creates a new class object, with a `foo` attribute set to `bar`, for example. The class produced can *itself* then be used to create instances. So classes are produced by metaclasses, just as instances are produced by classes.

You can produce your own metaclasses by inheriting from `type`, opening a weird and wonderful world of class behaviour.

Calling an unbound method by passing in a separate instance is not really a good example of using classes as an object. All you did was use the initial reference (the class name) to look up the method, then pass in an instance of the class as the first parameter to stand in for `self`.

Comment: Thanks for those useful information.So,classes are instances of metaclasses and objects are instances of classes.So does that mean I can create instances of instances in python?That seems to be confusing!

Comment: No, *instances* are objects created from classes. Classes are objects too, but created from metaclasses. Functions are objects, methods are objects, files are objects, *everything in Python is an object*.

Comment: What happens is that metaclasses and classes, like functions are *callable* objects. And when you call them they produce *something*; in Design Pattern language they are called *factories*.

Comment: Okay,my first confusion is gone.Now if everything in python is an object,then are metaclasses objects too?

Comment: Metaclasses are objects too. Did I mention the term *everything* yet?